# How to create a disk image with a partition table that can be easily resized to the target device?

Tags: filesystems, partition, ext3

I want to create a disk image with two partition, boot partition and rootfs partition.

I want boot to be a fixed size and rootfs to be easily resizeable to fill the target device after the image is `dd`ed to it.

Resizing file system using `resize2fs` is trivial, but manipulating the partition table is not.

Is there a way to let rootfs partition and file system fill the whole drive safely?

Comment: It depends on which OS you're on as to which partition tools you can use.  I think it's probably safer and a little easier to add another partition and mkfs on it, if that would work for your situation.

Comment: @RobertL That's what I was thinking last night. The OS is a custom Yocto Linux and is for a embedded system. This system actually does not require a large rootfs and the large amount of data generated by the system could and maybe should be placed in a separate partition.

Comment: A separate partition also makes it easier to upgrade the OS without touching the data partition.

Answer (score 0):

Make the /boot and swap (if any) partitions the first partition(s), and / the last partition.

/ can then easily be resized to take up the rest of the disk.

If you need any other partitions, also put them before the / partition.

BTW, you might want to look into [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).  It can do this kind of partition resizing automatically.

Comment: "/ can then `easily` be resized to take up the rest of the disk." Please provide more on the `easily` which is what I'm asking in the question.

Comment: i thought you wanted to know how to set things up so that resizing would be easy.  Anyway, you can use `gparted` as a graphical tool to resize partitions (it will also automatically resize the fs too), or you can use `parted` on he command-line, using parted's `resizepart` command.  if you've set things up as i described above, you can just extend the rootfs to the end of the disk.  You'll need to run `resize2fs` to resize the fs after the partition has been resized.